# Why Next Js application throws SIGNIN_OAUTH_ERROR remotely when trying to sign in to Cognito provider?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I have a nsxtJs app and I have used next-auth v4 for the authentication with cognito Provider. It's working fine locally. After the signing it's redirecting to desired path. But when I deploy the code as an AWS fargate service, after the signin it's throwing below error in the CW logs.

```
[next-auth][error][SIGNIN_OAUTH_ERROR] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#signin_oauth_error only valid absolute URLs can be requested {
error: {
message: 'only valid absolute URLs can be requested',
stack: 'TypeError: only valid absolute URLs can be requested\n' +
  '    at Function.request (/app/node_modules/openid-client/lib/helpers/request.js:68:11)\n' +
  '    at Function.discover (/app/node_modules/openid-client/lib/issuer.js:144:38)\n' +
  '    at openidClient (/app/node_modules/next-auth/core/lib/oauth/client.js:16:41)\n' +
  '    at getAuthorizationUrl (/app/node_modules/next-auth/core/lib/oauth/authorization-url.js:70:49)\n' +
  '    at Object.signin (/app/node_modules/next-auth/core/routes/signin.js:38:60)\n' +
  '    at AuthHandler (/app/node_modules/next-auth/core/index.js:253:39)\n' +
  '    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)\n' +
  '    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)\n' +
  '    at async NextAuthHandler (/app/node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:24:19)\n' +
  '    at async /app/node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:60:32',
name: 'TypeError'
},
providerId: 'cognito',
message: 'only valid absolute URLs can be requested'
}
```

This is my docker file

```
FROM node:16-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
ENV NEXTAUTH_URL=https://mediamanager-dev.cloud.sysco.net
RUN npm run build
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

and this is my api/auth/[...nextauth].tsx file

```
import NextAuth, { NextAuthOptions  } from 'next-auth'
import CognitoProvider from "next-auth/providers/cognito";

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
providers: [
  CognitoProvider({
    clientId: process.env.COGNITO_CLIENT_ID || '',
    clientSecret: process.env.COGNITO_CLIENT_SECRET || '',
    issuer: process.env.COGNITO_ISSUER || '',
  })
],
secret:'ttdVYyZt7HDkPlgET5CEY8Anchurq86KZh8Nddf2Xk8=',
callbacks: {
async jwt({token, account}) {
  if (account) {
    token.access_token = account.access_token
    token.id_token = account.id_token
  }
  return token
 }
 }
 }
export default NextAuth(authOptions)
```

and the .env.local file

```
NEXTAUTH_URL=https://<domain>
NEXTAUTH_SECRET=<>
COGNITO_CLIENT_ID=<cl id>
COGNITO_CLIENT_SECRET=<cl secret>
COGNITO_ISSUER=<issue>
```

and this is the component code.

```
import {signIn} from 'next-auth/react'
<Button href='/dashboard' onClick={(e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        signIn('cognito', {callbackUrl: `${window.location.origin}/dashboard`})
        }} 
        appearance={appearance} style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>
        {text}
</Button>
```

What may ne missing here? I have attached an image after pressing the sign in button

[image]